# Remove specific pattern of lines from file with Gradle task

Tags: java, gradle

I am trying to remove the specific pattern of lines from the A.txt file with the below code in gradle

File is having below content

A.txt

```
nda.url=@nda.url@

# SAP Settings
sdap.url=@sap.url@
sap.prefix.search=@sap.prefix.search@
sap.prefix.group=@sap.prefix.group@

# SMTP/Email Settings
smtp.host=@smtp.host@                                          
smtp.enabled=true
```

I am trying to remove all the lines which is having this pattern =@*@ with gradle task from the above file and after that my file should have only those values which doesn't have that pattern.

I am trying to do it with below gradle code but it is not working

```
task removeandcopy(type:Copy) {
  def regexp = new org.apache.tools.ant.types.RegularExpression()
  regexp.pattern = '=@*@'

  from(projectDir) {
    include 'A.txt'
    filter(org.apache.tools.ant.filters.LineContainsRegExp, regexps:[regexp])
  }
  into "outputDir"
}
```

Can someone let me know what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I am able to achieve this in below manner and it is working fine.

```
task deleteEmptyVariable(dependsOn: passLocalProp) << {
    description "This function will remove all those variable which doesn't have value"
    FileTree  propFiles = fileTree('build/orignal/local.properties.template') {

    }
    String regex = ".*=@.*@"
    propFiles.each { File propFile ->
        println "Start replacing regex on $propFile.name"
        String content = propFile.getText()
        content = content.replaceAll(regex, "")
        propFile.setText(content)
    }
}
```